# xmonad UrgencyHook not working

Tags: xmonad

I'm using xmonad and want to enable the UrgencyHook feature so I know when someone talks to me in pidgin. For that I use the `XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook`module. I use dzen2 and conky for the status bar, and I just want xmonad to highlight the workspace pidgin is on when it requires attention.

Now I tried to use the dzenUrgencyHook and it worked, but I actually want xmonad to highlight the workspace in the current dzen2 bar I have popped, and this is where the trouble comes, as nothing happens.

So it seems like a configuration problem, since with dzenUrgencyHook works I assume pidgin is in fact sending the WM_URGENT signal.

Here's the config I have right now:

```
-- ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs
-- Imports {{{
import XMonad
-- Prompt
import XMonad.Prompt
import XMonad.Prompt.RunOrRaise (runOrRaisePrompt)
import XMonad.Prompt.AppendFile (appendFilePrompt)
-- Hooks
import XMonad.Operations

import System.IO
import System.Exit

import XMonad.Util.Run


import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS

import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import XMonad.Hooks.FadeInactive
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders (smartBorders, noBorders)
import XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace (onWorkspace, onWorkspaces)
import XMonad.Layout.Reflect (reflectHoriz)
import XMonad.Layout.IM
import XMonad.Layout.SimpleFloat
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutHints
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier
import XMonad.Layout.Grid

import Data.Ratio ((%))

import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import qualified Data.Map as M

--}}}

-- Config {{{
-- Define Terminal
myTerminal      = "gnome-terminal"
-- Define modMask
modMask' :: KeyMask
modMask' = mod4Mask
-- Define workspaces
myWorkspaces    = ["1:main","2:web","3:vim","4:chat","5:music", "6:gimp", "7:misc"]
-- Dzen/Conky
myXmonadBar = "dzen2 -x '1440' -y '0' -h '24' -w '640' -ta 'l' -fg '#FFFFFF' -bg '#1B1D1E'"
myStatusBar = "conky -c /home/brafales/.xmonad/.conky_dzen | dzen2 -x '2080' -w '1040' -h '24' -ta 'r' -bg '#1B1D1E' -fg '#FFFFFF' -y '0'"
myBitmapsDir = "/home/brafales/.xmonad/dzen2"
--}}}
-- Main {{{
main = do
    dzenLeftBar <- spawnPipe myXmonadBar
    dzenRightBar <- spawnPipe myStatusBar
    xmonad $ withUrgencyHook NoUrgencyHook $ defaultConfig
      { terminal            = myTerminal
      , workspaces          = myWorkspaces
      , keys                = keys'
      , modMask             = modMask'
      , layoutHook          = layoutHook'
      , manageHook          = manageHook'
      , logHook             = myLogHook dzenLeftBar >> fadeInactiveLogHook 0xdddddddd
      , normalBorderColor   = colorNormalBorder
      , focusedBorderColor  = colorFocusedBorder
      , borderWidth         = 2
      , startupHook         = setWMName "LG3D"
}
--}}}


-- Hooks {{{
-- ManageHook {{{
manageHook' :: ManageHook
manageHook' = (composeAll . concat $
    [ [resource     =? r            --> doIgnore            |   r   <- myIgnores] -- ignore desktop
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "1:main"   |   c   <- myDev    ] -- move dev to main
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "2:web"    |   c   <- myWebs   ] -- move webs to main
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "3:vim"    |   c   <- myVim    ] -- move webs to main
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "4:chat"   |   c   <- myChat   ] -- move chat to chat
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "5:music"  |   c   <- myMusic  ] -- move music to music
    , [className    =? c            --> doShift  "6:gimp"   |   c   <- myGimp   ] -- move img to div
    , [className    =? c            --> doCenterFloat       |   c   <- myFloats ] -- float my floats
    , [name         =? n            --> doCenterFloat       |   n   <- myNames  ] -- float my names
    , [isFullscreen                 --> myDoFullFloat                           ]
    ]) 

    where

        role      = stringProperty "WM_WINDOW_ROLE"
        name      = stringProperty "WM_NAME"

        -- classnames
        myFloats  = ["Smplayer","MPlayer","VirtualBox","Xmessage","XFontSel","Downloads","Nm-connection-editor"]
        myWebs    = ["Firefox","Google-chrome","Chromium", "Chromium-browser"]
        myMovie   = ["Boxee","Trine"]
        myMusic   = ["Rhythmbox","Spotify"]
        myChat    = ["Pidgin","Buddy List"]
        myGimp    = ["Gimp"]
        myDev     = ["gnome-terminal"]
        myVim     = ["Gvim"]

        -- resources
        myIgnores = ["desktop","desktop_window","notify-osd","stalonetray","trayer"]

        -- names
        myNames   = ["bashrun","Google Chrome Options","Chromium Options"]

-- a trick for fullscreen but stil allow focusing of other WSs
myDoFullFloat :: ManageHook
myDoFullFloat = doF W.focusDown <+> doFullFloat
-- }}}
layoutHook'  =  onWorkspaces ["1:main","5:music"] customLayout $ 
                onWorkspaces ["6:gimp"] gimpLayout $ 
                onWorkspaces ["4:chat"] imLayout $
                customLayout2

--Bar
myLogHook :: Handle -> X ()
myLogHook h = dynamicLogWithPP $ defaultPP
    {
        ppCurrent           =   dzenColor "#ebac54" "#1B1D1E" . pad
      , ppVisible           =   dzenColor "white" "#1B1D1E" . pad
      , ppHidden            =   dzenColor "white" "#1B1D1E" . pad
      , ppHiddenNoWindows   =   dzenColor "#7b7b7b" "#1B1D1E" . pad
      , ppUrgent            =   dzenColor "black" "red" . pad
      , ppWsSep             =   " "
      , ppSep               =   "  |  "
      , ppLayout            =   dzenColor "#ebac54" "#1B1D1E" .
                                (\x -> case x of
                                    "ResizableTall"             ->      "^i(" ++ myBitmapsDir ++ "/tall.xbm)"
                                    "Mirror ResizableTall"      ->      "^i(" ++ myBitmapsDir ++ "/mtall.xbm)"
                                    "Full"                      ->      "^i(" ++ myBitmapsDir ++ "/full.xbm)"
                                    "Simple Float"              ->      "~"
                                    _                           ->      x
                                )
      , ppTitle             =   (" " ++) . dzenColor "white" "#1B1D1E" . dzenEscape
      , ppOutput            =   hPutStrLn h
    }

-- Layout
customLayout = avoidStruts $ tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full ||| simpleFloat
  where
    tiled   = ResizableTall 1 (2/100) (1/2) []

customLayout2 = avoidStruts $ Full ||| tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| simpleFloat
  where
    tiled   = ResizableTall 1 (2/100) (1/2) []

gimpLayout  = avoidStruts $ withIM (0.11) (Role "gimp-toolbox") $
              reflectHoriz $
              withIM (0.15) (Role "gimp-dock") Full

imLayout    = avoidStruts $ withIM (1%5) (And (ClassName "Pidgin") (Role "buddy_list")) Grid 
--}}}
-- Theme {{{
-- Color names are easier to remember:
colorOrange         = "#FD971F"
colorDarkGray       = "#1B1D1E"
colorPink           = "#F92672"
colorGreen          = "#A6E22E"
colorBlue           = "#66D9EF"
colorYellow         = "#E6DB74"
colorWhite          = "#CCCCC6"

colorNormalBorder   = "#CCCCC6"
colorFocusedBorder  = "#fd971f"


barFont  = "terminus"
barXFont = "inconsolata:size=12"
xftFont = "xft: inconsolata-14"
--}}}

-- Prompt Config {{{
mXPConfig :: XPConfig
mXPConfig =
    defaultXPConfig { font                  = barFont
                    , bgColor               = colorDarkGray
                    , fgColor               = colorGreen
                    , bgHLight              = colorGreen
                    , fgHLight              = colorDarkGray
                    , promptBorderWidth     = 0
                    , height                = 14
                    , historyFilter         = deleteConsecutive
                    }

-- Run or Raise Menu
largeXPConfig :: XPConfig
largeXPConfig = mXPConfig
                { font = xftFont
                , height = 22
                }
-- }}}
-- Key mapping {{{
keys' conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
    [ ((modMask,                    xK_p        ), runOrRaisePrompt largeXPConfig)
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_Return   ), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)
    , ((modMask,                    xK_F2       ), spawn "gmrun")
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_c        ), kill)
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_l        ), spawn "slock")
    -- Programs
    , ((0,                          xK_Print    ), spawn "scrot -e 'mv $f ~/screenshots/'")
    , ((modMask,                    xK_o        ), spawn "chromium-browser")
    , ((modMask,                    xK_m        ), spawn "nautilus --no-desktop --browser")
    -- Media Keys
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff12  ), spawn "amixer -q sset Headphone toggle")        -- XF86AudioMute
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff11  ), spawn "amixer -q sset Headphone 5%-")   -- XF86AudioLowerVolume
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff13  ), spawn "amixer -q sset Headphone 5%+")   -- XF86AudioRaiseVolume
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff14  ), spawn "rhythmbox-client --play-pause")
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff17  ), spawn "rhythmbox-client --next")
    , ((0,                          0x1008ff16  ), spawn "rhythmbox-client --previous")

    -- layouts
    , ((modMask,                    xK_space    ), sendMessage NextLayout)
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_space    ), setLayout $ XMonad.layoutHook conf)          -- reset layout on current desktop to default
    , ((modMask,                    xK_b        ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)
    , ((modMask,                    xK_n        ), refresh)
    , ((modMask,                    xK_Tab      ), windows W.focusDown)                         -- move focus to next window
    , ((modMask,                    xK_j        ), windows W.focusDown)
    , ((modMask,                    xK_k        ), windows W.focusUp  )
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_j        ), windows W.swapDown)                          -- swap the focused window with the next window
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_k        ), windows W.swapUp)                            -- swap the focused window with the previous window
    , ((modMask,                    xK_Return   ), windows W.swapMaster)
    , ((modMask,                    xK_t        ), withFocused $ windows . W.sink)              -- Push window back into tiling
    , ((modMask,                    xK_h        ), sendMessage Shrink)                          -- %! Shrink a master area
    , ((modMask,                    xK_l        ), sendMessage Expand)                          -- %! Expand a master area
    , ((modMask,                    xK_comma    ), sendMessage (IncMasterN 1))
    , ((modMask,                    xK_period   ), sendMessage (IncMasterN (-1)))


    -- workspaces
    , ((modMask .|. controlMask,   xK_Right     ), nextWS)
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,     xK_Right     ), shiftToNext)
    , ((modMask .|. controlMask,   xK_Left      ), prevWS)
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,     xK_Left      ), shiftToPrev)

    -- quit, or restart
    , ((modMask .|. shiftMask,      xK_q        ), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))
    , ((modMask,                    xK_q        ), spawn "killall conky dzen2 && && sleep 2 && /home/brafales/.cabal/bin/xmonad --recompile && /home/brafales/.cabal/bin/xmonad --restart")
    ]
    ++
    -- mod-[1..9] %! Switch to workspace N
    -- mod-shift-[1..9] %! Move client to workspace N
    [((m .|. modMask, k), windows $ f i)
        | (i, k) <- zip (XMonad.workspaces conf) [xK_1 .. xK_9]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.greedyView, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]
    ++

    --
    -- mod-{w,e,r}, Switch to physical/Xinerama screens 1, 2, or 3
    -- mod-shift-{w,e,r}, Move client to screen 1, 2, or 3
    --
    [((m .|. modMask, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
        | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_w, xK_e, xK_r] [0..]
        , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]

--}}}
-- vim:foldmethod=marker sw=4 sts=4 ts=4 tw=0 et ai nowrap
```

Now I expect the "4:chat" (where pidgin is running) to go to red background and black foreground, but actually nothing happens.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong since I've checked similar configurations and are apparently the same.

I'm running xmonad 0.9.2

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that for urgent workspaces, both `ppUrgent` and `ppHidden` are applied. Since you've used colour formatting in `ppHidden`, that overrides any subsequent colouring you might add to `ppUrgent`.

It's easily solved, however; simply extend `ppUrgent` to remove the formatting that `ppHidden` applies, with the `dzenStrip` function:

```
    , ppUrgent = dzenColor "black" "red" . pad . dzenStrip
```

Your urgency hook should then function without issue.

As an addendum, other functions may also be applied to urgent workspace highlighting. For example, in my own xmonad.hs, I apply:

```
    wrap ">" "<"
```

as part of my ppUrgent function, thus producing a display along the lines of `>1:im<`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try redirecting the output and handle the colouring with dzen tags for color 
StdoutUrgencyHook sounds promising

i personaly have

```
myUrgencyHook = withUrgencyHook dzenUrgencyHook
{ args = ["-x", "0", "-y", "184", "-h", "16", "-w", "320", "-ta ", "r", "-expand", "l", "-fg", "" ++ myUrgentFGColor ++ "", "-bg", "" ++ myNormalBGColor ++ "", "-fn", "" ++ myFont ++ ""] }
```

with

```
xmonad $ myUrgencyHook $ defaultConfig {
```

but have never tested it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that line :

```
xmonad $ withUrgencyHook NoUrgencyHook $ defaultConfig
```

change NoUrgencyHook to dzenUrgencyHook , or any wanted from http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-UrgencyHook.html
or write own:)